# TYPO3 render correct canonical of selected mountpoint

Tags: typo3, seo, canonical-link, typo3-10.x

When I set the `doktype` of a page to `Mount Point`
[image]

and then set `mount_pid_ol` to `Show the mounted page` the canonical-tag of the current, site is rendered. Not the canonical of the site selected in `mount_pid`.

[image]

Is that `Mount Point` option somehow limited with the core SEO plugin since also the whole SEO-Tab is missing after selecting `Mount Point`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have found a bug in the core extension. For sure with these settings, your canonical should be rendered off the selected page.

I've created an issue on forge for this and will fix this asap.

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/93300